# WPF ComboBox BorderBrush and BorderThickness don't work consistently in style

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, wpf-style

I'm trying to change the border of a ComboBox to be thicker and red based on a binding value, but the properties don't behave as expected.  The code below will correctly set the BorderThickness to 2 when Value is Null, but the BorderBrush doesn't get set to Red; I added the setter for Yellow to test, but it is also not working.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
          Margin="0,10"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.AllConfigurations}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Value}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

In contrast, the following code correctly sets the BorderBrush to Red, but it doesn't change the BorderThickness.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
          Margin="0,10"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.AllConfigurations}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"
          BorderBrush="Red"
          BorderThickness="2"/>
```

So, to summarize the problem as I understand it, BorderBrush changes the border color when set directly but not when set from a Setter within a Style; BorderThickness changes the border thickness when set from a Setter within a Style but not when set directly.  Can anyone please provide an explanation as to why this is happening and how I can make the border thicker and red when Value is Null?

Comment: The [default style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx) for combobox has the borderthickness hard coded to "1" so I'm not sure how that's effective here. Your BorderBrush however you should use a Storyboard with a ColorAnimation instead of a property change setter and it should work as desired. The Thickness though I believe you'll need to actually change the template to templatebinding to that property.